# Cannot connect to wifi on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, wpa-supplicant

I am trying to get a Wi-Fi connection on a CLI only server.  I have ethernet working.  I followed this guide but it will not connect.  https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/stacks/network/network-manager/docs/configure-wifi-connections

The adapter is on and I can see the available SSIDs

```
tom@hass:~$ nmcli d wifi list
IN-USE  SSID              MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY
        mynetwork         Infra  6     130 Mbit/s  89      ▂▄▆█  WPA2
        --                Infra  6     65 Mbit/s   89      ▂▄▆█  --
        othernetwork1     Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2
        mynetwork         Infra  11    130 Mbit/s  52      ▂▄__  WPA2
        mynetwork         Infra  1     130 Mbit/s  45      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2
        othernetwork2     Infra  3     52 Mbit/s   45      ▂▄__  WPA2
        othernetwork3     Infra  6     540 Mbit/s  42      ▂▄__  WPA2
```

However when I try to connect I get this:

```
tom@hass:~$ sudo nmcli d wifi connect mynetwork password mypassword
Error: Connection activation failed: (53) The Wi-Fi network could not be found.
```

`dmesg` shows:

```
[16371.487318] wlo1: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb
[16371.498759] wlo1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb (try 1/3)
[16371.561282] wlo1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb (try 2/3)
[16371.599289] wlo1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb (try 3/3)
[16371.654537] wlo1: authentication with xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb timed out
[16381.783587] wlo1: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:ad:a7:f3
[16381.790933] wlo1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:ad:a7:f3 (try 1/3)
[16381.817095] wlo1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:ad:a7:f3 (try 2/3)
[16381.852486] wlo1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:ad:a7:f3 (try 3/3)
[16381.874894] wlo1: authentication with xx:xx:xx:ad:a7:f3 timed out
[16396.028018] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
```

Output of `journalctl -xe`:

```
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass sudo[10725]:      tom : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/tom ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nmcli d wifi connect mynetwork password mypassword
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass sudo[10725]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by tom(uid=0)
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.5423] keyfile: add connection in-memory (a3494e63-4734-44ff-83de-bd33f8cbdd2b,"mynetwork 7")
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.5464] device (wlo1): Activation: starting connection 'mynetwork 7' (a3494e63-4734-44ff-83de-bd33f8cbdd2b)
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.5821] settings-connection[0x560511bb3a80,a3494e63-4734-44ff-83de-bd33f8cbdd2b]: write: successfully commited (keyfile: update /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/geauxtige
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.5825] audit: op="connection-add-activate" uuid="a3494e63-4734-44ff-83de-bd33f8cbdd2b" name="mynetwork 7" pid=10726 uid=0 result="success"
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.5934] device (wlo1): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.5941] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.5966] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.5982] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) access point 'mynetwork 7' has security, but secrets are required.
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.5983] device (wlo1): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.6077] device (wlo1): state change: need-auth -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.6087] device (wlo1): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.6104] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) connection 'mynetwork 7' has security, and secrets exist.  No new secrets needed.
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.6105] Config: added 'ssid' value 'mynetwork'
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.6106] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.6106] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-80:86400'
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.6107] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'WPA-PSK'
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.6107] Config: added 'auth_alg' value 'OPEN'
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.6107] Config: added 'psk' value '<hidden>'
Jul 02 12:26:07 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710767.6355] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 02 12:26:08 hass wpa_supplicant[1398]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:3e:fe:0f (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2462 MHz)
Jul 02 12:26:08 hass kernel: wlo1: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:3e:fe:0f
Jul 02 12:26:08 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710768.7438] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 02 12:26:08 hass kernel: wlo1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:3e:fe:0f (try 1/3)
Jul 02 12:26:08 hass kernel: wlo1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:3e:fe:0f (try 2/3)
Jul 02 12:26:08 hass kernel: wlo1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:3e:fe:0f (try 3/3)
Jul 02 12:26:08 hass kernel: wlo1: authentication with xx:xx:xx:3e:fe:0f timed out
Jul 02 12:26:08 hass wpa_supplicant[1398]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
Jul 02 12:26:08 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710768.9015] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jul 02 12:26:18 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710778.9046] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 02 12:26:18 hass wpa_supplicant[1398]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork"
Jul 02 12:26:18 hass wpa_supplicant[1398]: wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2412 MHz)
Jul 02 12:26:18 hass kernel: wlo1: authenticate with xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb
Jul 02 12:26:18 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710778.9829] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Jul 02 12:26:18 hass kernel: wlo1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb (try 1/3)
Jul 02 12:26:19 hass kernel: wlo1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb (try 2/3)
Jul 02 12:26:19 hass kernel: wlo1: send auth to xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb (try 3/3)
Jul 02 12:26:19 hass kernel: wlo1: authentication with xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb timed out
Jul 02 12:26:19 hass wpa_supplicant[1398]: wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork" auth_failures=2 duration=20 reason=CONN_FAILED
Jul 02 12:26:19 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710779.1377] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected
Jul 02 12:26:29 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710789.1410] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning
Jul 02 12:26:32 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <warn>  [1593710792.8984] device (wlo1): Activation: (wifi) association took too long, failing activation
Jul 02 12:26:32 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710792.8985] device (wlo1): state change: config -> failed (reason 'ssid-not-found', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 02 12:26:32 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710792.8991] manager: NetworkManager state is now DISCONNECTED
Jul 02 12:26:32 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <warn>  [1593710792.9009] device (wlo1): Activation: failed for connection 'mynetwork 7'
Jul 02 12:26:32 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710792.9074] device (wlo1): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jul 02 12:26:32 hass kernel: IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlo1: link is not ready
Jul 02 12:26:32 hass sudo[10725]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Jul 02 12:26:34 hass NetworkManager[1392]: <info>  [1593710794.0153] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: scanning -> disconnected
```

I then tried connecting with WPA supplicant

```
tom@hass:~$ sudo wpa_supplicant -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlo1
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:ad:a7:f3 (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2437 MHz)
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:3e:fe:0f (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2462 MHz)
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:ad:a7:f3 (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2437 MHz)
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2412 MHz)
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:3e:fe:0f (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2462 MHz)
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:ec:xx:ad:a7:f3 (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2437 MHz)
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork"
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2412 MHz)
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork" auth_failures=2 duration=23 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork"
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:ad:a7:f3 (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2437 MHz)
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork" auth_failures=3 duration=46 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork"
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:3e:fe:0f (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2462 MHz)
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork" auth_failures=4 duration=77 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork"
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:6f:56:cb (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2412 MHz)
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork" auth_failures=5 duration=75 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork"
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:ad:a7:f3 (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2437 MHz)
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork" auth_failures=6 duration=143 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork"
wlo1: SME: Trying to authenticate with xx:xx:xx:3e:fe:0f (SSID='mynetwork' freq=2462 MHz)
wlo1: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="mynetwork" auth_failures=7 duration=135 reason=CONN_FAILED
```

I confirmed spellings and password countless times.

I just setup temp wifi network and tested on that.  I get the same errors

```
tom@hass:~$ sudo nmcli d wifi connect testwifi password password
Error: Connection activation failed: (53) The Wi-Fi network could not be found.
```

Comment: You may also want to try `nmtui` .

Comment: I see a lot of authorization issues. Do you have control of the WiFi network?  Is there MAC filtering possibly?  Can you connect to **any** wireless network?  Why is your network taking up 3 channels?

Comment: Yes I have control. It's my home network.  Other devices connect fine.  I have 3 Unifi APs.  No MAC filtering.  I'm not seeing anything in the Unifi logs

Comment: Using nmtui I get " Could not activate connection:     Activation failed: The Wi-Fi network could not be found "

Comment: Yes I created a wifi hot spot on my phone and tried to connect to that.   Single channel on the 2.4Ghz.  Getting the same errors.